# how to switch/select what code to use while doing cross compiling

Tags: go, cross-compiling

I am using the `+build` tag to define what to compile based on the architecture.

For code that only runs on UNIX/BSD I use this:

```
// +build freebsd netbsd openbsd dragonfly darwin 
// +build amd64
```

And for linux I have:

```
// +build linux
```

The name of the files containing the source code is like this:

```
watchpid.go
watchpid_linux.go
```

The files contains the same method signature but different approaches.

```
func watchPid() {
  // kqueue for UNIX, BSD
  // for loop cross-platform version (linux)
}
```

In case I would like to test/compile for example the linux version on a Mac OS X, is there a easy switch/trick to do it instead of editing the `+build` tag  or renaming the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GOOS=linux go build`

Check out https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Environment_variables and http://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5